# OMNeT++ .ini file parameters

Tags: omnet++

I use OMNeT++ and I have this question about **.ini files**:

Why do we sometimes use `*` and sometimes we use `**` to set parameters of NED modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the OMNeT++ Manual (Section 3.6.1)

`*` means `A wildcard for any substring not containing a dot`

`**` means `A wildard for any sequence of characters including dots, so it can match multiple path elements`

---

Example:
Lets assume you have the following modules:
`aaa.bbb.value` and `aaa.ddd.value` and `ccc.bbb.value`

`**.value = 0` would address all modules, the path before is not important.

`aaa.*.value = 0` would address the value element of `aaa.bbb.value` and `aaa.ddd.value`. `ccc.bbb.value` is not addressed because the wildcard is only for the middle substring of the path, as it contains no dots.